# Why $\int_{\partial(\Omega \backslash B_p(y))}v(x) \Delta u(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}v(x)\Delta u(x)dx$ as $p \to 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $v(x)= \Gamma(x-y)=\frac{1}{n(2-n)w_n}x^{2-n}$ when $n>2$.

Then $\int_{\partial(\Omega \backslash B_p(y))}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=\int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}+\int_{\partial B_p(y)}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}$.

Since $\int_{\partial B_p(y)}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=-\frac{1}{nw_np^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_p(y)}u=-u(y)$.
We have $$\int_{\partial(\Omega \backslash B_p(y))}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=\int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}+\int_{\partial B_p(y)}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=\int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}-u(y)$$ as $p \to 0$.

Similarly, $\int_{\partial(\Omega \backslash B_p(y))}u\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}=\int_{\partial\Omega}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}+\int_{\partial B_p(y)}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=\int_{\partial\Omega}v\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ as $p \to 0$.

My question is how we get $\int_{(\Omega \backslash B_p(y))}v(x) \Delta u(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}v(x)\Delta u(x)dx$ as $p \to 0$? The book says since $v(x) \in L^1(\Omega)$ which I don't understand. Why we don't need argument as above?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you know about $u$?

Comment: @mrf I think $u\in C^2(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you assume that $u \in C^2$, $\Delta u$ is bounded near $y$, so
$$
\left| \int_{B_\rho(y)} v\Delta u \right| \le M \int_{B_\rho(y)} |v|
$$
but this tends to $0$ as $\rho\to 0$, since $v \in L^1$. In other words
$$
\int_{\Omega \setminus B_\rho(y)} v\Delta u = 
\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u - \int_{B_\rho(y)} v\Delta u \to 
\int_{\Omega} v\Delta u.$$
(It looks like your formulas hava a few $\partial$ too many.)